# use one function to getattr for either functions or regular attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, getattr, getattribute

I have the following code:

```
In [38]: %paste
def set_session_attribute(obj, attribute):
    if attribute.endswith('()'):
        attribute = attribute.replace('()', '')
        return getattr(obj, attribute)()
    else:
        return getattr(obj, attribute)


class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.legs = 4
    def length(self):
        return 6

## -- End pasted text --

In [39]: x = Thing()

In [40]: y = set_session_attribute(x, 'legs')

In [41]: y
Out[41]: 4

In [42]: z = set_session_attribute(x, 'length()')

In [43]: z
Out[43]: 6
```

This is because calling with `"length()"` didn't work (`AttributeError, no attribute length()`)

Is there a shorter, more maintainable way to make functions like this? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solution 1

You can make `length` a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property):

```
class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.legs = 4
    @property
    def length(self):
        return 6

>>> thing = Thing()
>>> thing.legs
4
>>> thing.length
6
```

If you really want to use your function:

```
def set_session_attribute(obj, attribute):
    return getattr(obj, attribute)

>>> set_session_attribute(thing, 'legs')
4
>>> set_session_attribute(thing, 'length')
6
```

If you cannot change the source of `thing` directly, you can do after importing the class:

```
class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.legs = 4
    def length(self):
        return 6
```

Here:

```
Thing.length2 = property(Thing.length)

>>> thing = Thing()
>>> thing.length2
6
```

## Solution 2

Alternatively, you can check if the attribute is callable:

```
class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.legs = 4
    def length(self):
        return 6

def set_session_attribute(obj, attribute):
    attr = getattr(obj, attribute)
    if hasattr(attr, '__call__'):  # may use `callable()`
        return attr()
    return attr

>> thing = Thing()
>>> set_session_attribute(thing, 'legs')
4
>>> set_session_attribute(thing, 'length')
6
```

Comment: I can't change the function I'm trying to call

Comment: Do you mean the function `set_session_attribute` or a method in the class `Thing` or another function?

Comment: I can't change anything in the classes I'm accessing, like Thing(), a huge system depends on those

Comment: Added a second solution that does not need to change `Thing`.

Comment: that if/return is better than what I ended with yesterday. ty

Answer (score 1):

Decorate those methods with `@property`, which you feel should have semantics of data rather than a method.

```
class Thing:
    @property
    def length(self):
        return somedata

    @property.setter
    def length(self, value):
        somename = value

t = Thing()
l0 = t.length
t.length = l1
```

So this is a getter. There is also a setter `@property.setter`, where you can do `t.length = somedata` instead of something like `t.set_length(somedata)`